# Lawvere's fixed point theorem in agda

Tags: proof, agda, theorem-proving, category-theory

I was struggling to prove a more basic version of [lawvere's fixed point theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere%27s+fixed+point+theorem) in agda. Precisely I am trying to figure out the proof for the bottom theorem.

```
surjective : {A : _} {B : _} → (A → B) → Set
surjective {B = B} f = (b : B) → ∃ λ a → f a ≡ b

fixedPoint : {A : _} → (A → A) -> Set
fixedPoint f = ∃ λ a → f a ≡ a

lawvere : {A : _} {B : _}
        → (ϕ : A → A → B) → (surjective ϕ) → (f : B → B) →
        fixedPoint f
lawvere = ?
```

General tips about how to approach similar proofs involving existentials would also be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried adapting the proof from the nLab article? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @mudri defining q is pretty straight forward (it's just `q = λ a → f (ϕ a a)`), but I had trouble creating p.

Comment: @Aceshinigami Pass `q` to `surjective ϕ`, it will return a pair of `p` and a proof.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher ok this was along the lines of what I was thinking, but when I decompose `(surjective ϕ) q` I seem to get a useful `p`, but I have no idea how to use the accompanying proof to prove `ϕ a a = f ( ϕ a a )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think my problem was hesitancy to use equational reasoning which I often have trouble with in agda. The solution I eventually found was:

```
lawvere : {A : _} {B : _}
        → (ϕ : A → A → B) → (surjective ϕ) → (f : B → B) →
        fixedPoint f
lawvere {A} {B} ϕ surj f = ϕ p p , sym proof
  where
    q = λ a → f (ϕ a a)
    p = Σ.fst (surj q)
    proof =
      begin
        ϕ p p
      ≡⟨ (cong-app (Σ.snd (surj q)) p) ⟩
        q p
      ≡⟨ refl ⟩
        (λ a → f (ϕ a a)) p
      ≡⟨ refl ⟩
        f (ϕ p p)
      ∎
```